# flushing the content of the page to the navigation bar

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have the following code for the navigation bar on my asp.net page:

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;position:absolute;top:0px;left:50%;transform:translateX(-50%);width:80%" >
```

Navbar

I want the background of the content to be of white color and totally flush to the top of the Navigation bar, and also of same size as navigation bar. Is it possible to do that? I have the following code:

```
  <body style="background-color:cadetblue">
    <form runat="server" >
      <nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;position:absolute;top:0px;left:50%;transform:translateX(-50%);width:80%" >
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

</nav>
        <div  style="background-color:white;width:100%" class="container body-content" >
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
         </form>
</body>
```

with the above styling, I can see the white background, but not all the way flushed to the navigation bar and there is a space in between the navigation bar and white content. How can I reduce this space and make the same width as nav bar. Below is the image

[image]

I want to create something like this:

[image]

I am using bootstrap-grid.css for stylesheet. Below is the css for container and body content classes:

```
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .jumbotron {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .body-content {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

and this is the css for container:

```
.container,
.container-fluid,
.container-sm,
.container-md,
.container-lg,
.container-xl {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container, .container-sm {
    max-width: 540px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container, .container-sm, .container-md {
    max-width: 720px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container, .container-sm, .container-md, .container-lg {
    max-width: 960px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container, .container-sm, .container-md, .container-lg, .container-xl {
    max-width: 1140px;
  }
}
```

Comment: What margins or padding are there within the `container` and `body-content` classes? What do you see when you inspect the elements using the browsers development tools?

Comment: Use a reset on margin and padding for the document and see if it continues to add a small margin there on top of the nav bar... Or inspect the element in inspector and see where any margin/padding is being inherited from.

Comment: You really should add your CSS code to this question...

Comment: I am using bootstrap-grid.css for stylesheet.

Comment: Note that the `hr` tag has a margin by default. This will become less of an issue once you have content in your page above the footer. Also consider using border instead of `hr`

Comment: I pasted the css for container and body-content